# MATLAB: logic behind bitand and get all possible states

Tags: matlab, binary, bit-manipulation

I was provided with this code

```
m0=0.8;
m1=1.2;
k=6; %where k can take values between 2 and 10;
kbar=2^k;
g_m = [0:(kbar-1)];

for i = 1: (kbar)
  g=1;
  for j=0:(kbar-1)
    if(bitand(g_m(i),2^j))~=0
      g=g*m1;
    else
      g=g*m0;
    end
  end
  g_m(i)=g %results in a 1xN vector where N = all the possible states
end
```

My question is why the function of `bitand` allows you to generate all the possible "states"?
I am not too sure if I really understand the logic behind bitand beside searching if the values that it compares have a `bit = 1`, hence `ans=1`.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to fix this and avoid further confusion - just hit the `|edit|` link above.

Comment: Yes edited. I choose value `k` between 2 and 10, then `kbar = 2^k`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bitand takes 2 values, converts them into binary, makes logical AND between the two values and returns the result form the logical AND as a decimal number. so for 2 given numbers, it returns only one value

Comment: ok, but then why is `bitand` allows me to get all the possible states?

Comment: you get the all possible states because of the 2 for loops you are in.

Comment: does a code like the one above that uses the `bitand` command implies a Hadamard product?

Comment: yes, it does something like that. since you could draw the numbers as 1*N matrices containing values of 0 and 1. And if in the both matrices, at the same index you have 1, you get 1, otherwise you get 0